# Trying to Gather all tweets from the past 24hours and put them into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

Im trying to gather all the tweets from the last 24 hours and put them into a CSV file

When i do this i get

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not datetime.datetime
```

As an error

Can anyone help tell me how to get rid of this error and any other improvements that could possibly be made to the code

```
def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
# Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

# authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
alltweets = []    

# make initial request for most recent tweets (20 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.home_timeline (screen_name=screen_name, count=20)

# save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

# save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

page = 1
deadend = False



while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

        # all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.home_timeline(screen_name=screen_name, count=20, max_id=oldest,  page = page)

        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        # update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

        for tweet in alltweets:

            if (datetime.datetime.now() - tweet.created_at).days < 1:

                 # transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv    
                 outtweets = [tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")]

            else:
                 deadend = True
                 return
        if not deadend:
             page += 1
             time.sleep(10)

# write the csv    
with open('%s_tweetsBQ.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["id", "created_at", "text"])
    writer.writerows(outtweets)
pass

print ("CSV written")

if __name__ == '__main__':
# pass in the username of the account you want to download
get_all_tweets("BQ")
```

***Edit***

```
(most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Barry\workspace\TwitterTest\Test1\MGo.py", line 77, in    <module>
  get_all_tweets("BQ")
File "C:\Users\Barry\workspace\TwitterTest\Test1\MGo.py", line 70, in get_all_tweets
writer.writerows(outtweets)
 _csv.Error: iterable expected, not datetime.datetime
```

**EDIT 2**

```
for row in outtweets:
            date_str,time_str, entries_str = row.split()
            #print(a_date,a_time, entries)
            a_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M:%S")
            for e in entries_str.split(','): 
                 # write the csv    
                 with open('%s_tweetsBQ.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
                     writer = csv.writer(f)
                     writer.writerow(["id", "created_at", "text"])
                     writer.writerows(outtweets)
                 pass
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and post the **full text** of the traceback.

Comment: Indentations fixed, Going to add the traceback to the question

Comment: use the [edit] function to do what I asked. Don't post code or tracebacks in comments, they're impossible to read.

Comment: Sorry was my first time adding them here didnt know, i put them in the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outtweets` only ever contains a *single row* of data. `writer.writerows()` expects a list of rows, that is, a list of lists:

```
[
  [columns, in, row, 1],
  [columns, in, row, 2],
]
```

You are setting `outtweets` like this:

```
outtweets = [tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")]
```

That's just a single row.  To pass this to `writerows`, you need to accumulate each row of data into a list, and then pass that list to `writerows`.

Comment: Thanks, im completely new to this, can you tell me how i would put the rows into lists?

Comment: If you have a list, you can append something to it with the `append` method.  As in `mylist = []; mylist.append(some_value)`. Or even `my_list.append(some_other_list)`. Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: so i should create an instance of the list before the loop and then append at each iteration of the loop?